# How to control height of "Like" button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

The `button-count` Layout Style height of the "Like" button and corresponding counter block is 20px high. Is there any way to shrink that block to 16px using css of jQuery or any other method?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be done. The only customization you can do is what you see here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

See this article on why it's so difficult to resize iframes:

http://css-tricks.com/cross-domain-iframe-resizing/

Comment: Ok, thanks @GilBirman. I did read the Like button code generation page and didn't see anything on user controls for the div/img height. So I thought I would reach out here.

Comment: My iFrame is shown as 19px and the Like button is 23px.  Any ideas on how to change this?  Otherwise the bottom is cut off.

Comment: To avoid the bottom of the Like button being cut off, define the height of the container element.

Comment: This is untrue. Here's a few examples of the size being changed: http://www.intuit.com/website-building-software/blog/2011/06/how-to-set-up-a-facebook-%E2%80%9Clike%E2%80%9D-button-on-your-blog-posts/ http://www.mercedes-benz.com

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can hide whatever you like by wrapping it with a div and doing some css. Or you can !important override any of the CSS facebook uses by doing it in your own stylesheet.  Just open up your page in firebug after adding the button and you can figure out what css to override.  Honestly it's not worth it though, the facebook iframe for their button tears up android browsers and slows down every page you put it on.

I added the button to a page and only wanted the button not a count or their blown out text message beside it. so I created a div with the id="facebook" and wrapped it around the div they give you on the dev site.  Then added this CSS to my stylesheet.

```
#facebook {
max-width:42px;
max-height:20px;
overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
}
```

You can use a couple of div's to wrap it then change the centering of the button as well using negative margins on the inner div.  But again it's not honestly worth it to me so I stopped sending links to facebook and stick with twitter and pinterest.

Hope that helps.